# Azure Active Directory Users Deserialize Json to List Model

Tags: azure, json-deserialization, azure-active-directory

I want to deserialize Json result into a model. What I see is in authentication to get a single user from AD after you post your data and receive user u can easily transfer result to a model by

```
UserProfile profile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserProfile>(responseString);
```

which is awesome and here is userProfileModel which is created automatically

```
public class UserProfile
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string GivenName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

what I want to do is I want to deserialize the Jsonresult which contains list of users. What should I write instead of UserProfile? Does Azuree Active Directory have any Model for List of Users ? ( Ive tried AzureTest.Models.Users and it returned null so we can say it doesnt work :/)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here the answer :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2014/03/17/identity-in-your-own-apps-with-windows-azure-active-directory-part-4.aspx

best regards,

F. OGUER

Comment: [Link only answers are not good](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Please add ad additional explanation, may be with quoting of most relevant part.